# Cannot call a certain function twice in AngularJS

Tags: function, http, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have a bit of Angular code that I cannot seem to debug.  The page on load renders all of my groups perfectly in the navigation drop down bar.  When I go to click on one of the group, the messagesIndex function is called and all of the messages from that group will be displayed normally and at this point everything is working fine.  The problem is when I go to click on another group, or even the same group, the messagesIndex function does not load a second time.

I have spent a lot of time trying to debug this issue to no avail, but I have narrowed down exactly where the problem is occurring, there just doesn't seem to be any issues there that I can find.

I replaced the contents of the messagesIndex function with just $scope.groupID, and outputted the result along with a random number.  the groupID displayed along with the random number, and every time I clicked different groups different IDs and random numbers appeared, which means that the JADE/HTML is functioning properly and the function headers are golden.

I then took the original messagesIndex function and added $scope.random1 and scope.random2 with random numbers assigned to them to both the beginning and the end of the function, both before and after the HTTP request. When I called the function the first time, both random numbers generated and were outputted, though the http request is asynchronous all values were returned normally, hinting that the function called completely, unless there was an issue with the HTTP request dragging on after the success response?  Then when I went to call it again by clicking another group. neither of the random numbers changed, showing that the function either did not call at all, or it stopped before executing the first line of code within it.

frankly speaking I am stumped. The code looks basically Identical to many working HTTP request, yet for some reason I cannot call it twice.

Below is the AngularJS code:

```
angular.module('angular-client').controller('GroupMeCtrl',
['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache', 'Auth', function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

  $scope.groupsIndex = function(){
      $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups?token=' + token,
        cache: $templateCache
      }).
          success(function(data, status) {
              $scope.groupsIndex = data.response;
              $scope.stat = status;       
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.groupsIndex = data.response;
              $scope.stat = status || "Request failed"; 
          });
  };

  $scope.messagesIndex = function($groupID){
      $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/' + $groupID + '/messages?token=' + token,
        cache: $templateCache
      }).
          success(function(data, status) {
              $scope.messagesIndex = data;
              $scope.stat = status;       
          }).
          error(function(data, status) {
              $scope.messagesIndex = data.response;
              $scope.stat = status || "Request failed";
          });
  };

}]);
```

And below here is my JADE:

```
li.dropdown
    a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
        | Groups
        b.caret
    ul.dropdown-menu
        li(ng-repeat="group in groupsIndex")
            a(ng-click="messagesIndex(group.id)") {{group.name}}



.message-box(ng-repeat="message in messagesIndex.response.messages")
    .avatar-container
        img(src="{{message.avatar_url}}").avatar
    .text
        .user-name
            {{message.name}}
        span
            {{message.text}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the function with the data returned:

```
$scope.messagesIndex = function($groupID){
...
$scope.messagesIndex = data;
...
$scope.messagesIndex = data.response;
```

`$scope.messagesIndex` can't equal a function and the data you receive.